# Nested folder paths for WordPress multisite

Tags: multisite, directory

I'm looking to implement a WordPress multisite with nested folder paths.

Having read this blog - http://www.paulund.co.uk/wordpress-multisite-nested-paths - I just wondered if anyone had positive / negative experiences with it.

E.g. are there any technical gotchas or has this been wrapped into more recent WP code?

Comment: What is your specific problem? Note that our site is not a forum for open ended discussions.

Comment: Well, a good start would be to answer whether it has been wrapped into more recent WP code.